# Url rewriting a Regex help

Tags: regex, url-rewriting

What Regex do I need for match this url:

Match:

```
1234
1234/
1234/article-name
```

Don't match:

```
1234absd
1234absd/article-name
1234/article.aspx
1234/any.dot.in.the.url
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
^\d+(?:\/[\w-]*)?$
```

This matches a non-empty sequence of digits at the beginning of the string, followed by an optional suffix of a `/` and a (possibly empty) sequence of word characters (letters, digits, underscore) and a `-`.

This matches ([see on rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/OA9YUDUpEs)):

```
1234
1234/
1234/article-name
42/section_13
```

But not:

```
1234absd
1234absd/article-name
1234/article.aspx
1234/any.dot.in.the.url
007/james/bond
```

---

#### No parenthesis regex

You shouldn't need to do this, but if you can't use parenthesis at all, you can always expand to alternation:

```
^\d+$|^\d+\/$|^\d+\/[\w-]*$
```

Comment: @stacker: Rubular is nice. If you have any problem with the regex, just link me to your rubular test and explain what didn't go as expected, etc, and I'll help you find the more specific regex for your need.

Answer (score 1):

```
^\d+(/?)|(/[a-zA-Z-]+)$
```

That may work. or not. Hope it helps

Comment: The problem here is that `()` has a special meaning in IIS7 url rewriting. I'm looking for a way to escape them.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this ll help u ........

```
        string data = "1234/article-name";
        Regex Constant = new Regex("(?<NUMBERS>([0-9]+))?(//)?(?<DATA>([a-zA-Z-]*))?");
        MatchCollection mc;
        mc = Constant.Matches(data,0);
        if (mc.Count>0)
        {
            for (int l_nIndex = 0; l_nIndex < mc.Count; l_nIndex++)
            {
                string l_strNum = mc[l_nIndex].Groups["NUMBERS"].Value;
                string l_strData = mc[l_nIndex].Groups["DATA"].Value;
            }
        }
```